# In a replica set, why primary instance has almost same no of connection as of secondary instance in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have replica set with 1 primary, 2 secondary and 1 arbiter instance, in which no of connection to Primary and secondary are almost same. Why the connection is high in primary, while it should be only 1 are as much we have no of app server which are pointing to Primary for write operations. Please let us know.

Comment: And what exactly is your question? This part is a bit unclear "Why the connection is high in primary, while it should be only 1 are as much we have no of app server which are pointing to Primary for write operations. "

Comment: @Martin, we have set read operation to secondary instance in a replica set, and we did at code level, but I want to know why no of connection is increasing continuously to Primary as well while read operation is happening only in Secondary(connection in secondary also increase) and very few write operation is going on in Primary.

Answer (score 0):

> By default, an application directs its read operations to the primary
>   member in a replica set. Because write operations are issued to the
>   single primary, reading from the primary returns the latest version of
>   a document.

But In some circumstances, two nodes in a replica set may transiently believe that they are the primary, but at most, one of them will be able to complete writes with {w: majority} write concern. The node that can complete {w: majority} writes is the current primary, and the other node is a former primary that has not yet recognized its demotion, typically due to a network partition. When this occurs, clients that connect to the former primary may observe stale data despite having requested read preference primary.

For an application that does not require fully up-to-date data, you can improve read throughput or reduce latency by distributing some or all reads to secondary members of the replica set.

> So Read preference describes how MongoDB clients route read operations to  the members of a replica set.

In mongoDB have 5 Read Preference Modes.

1. `primary`Default mode. All operations read from the current replica
   set primary.
2. `primaryPreferred`   In most situations, operations read
   from the primary but if it is unavailable, operations read from
   secondary members.
3. `secondary` All operations read from the
   secondary members of the replica set.
4. `secondaryPreferred` In most
   situations, operations read from secondary members but if no
   secondary members are available, operations read from the primary.
5. `nearest` Operations read from member of the replica set with the
   least network latency, irrespective of the member’s type.

How to use-

`db.collection.find().readPref( { mode: 'nearest', tags: [ {'dc': 'east'} ] } )`

More @ [MongoDB Docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/read-preference/#edge-cases-2-primaries)

You can also Call the setReadPref() method on a Mongo connection object to control how the client will route all queries to members of the replica set.

ex- `db.getMongo().setReadPref('primaryPreferred')`

More @ [MongoDB Docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Mongo.setReadPref/#Mongo.setReadPref)

Comment: I know, we can set read operation to secondary in a replica set, and we did at code level, but I want to know why no of connection is increasing continuously to Primary as well while read operation is happening only in Secondary and very few write operation is going on in Primary.

Comment: @MukeshKumar use setReadPref('primaryPreferred') in your  connection. If you want to run query to randomly amongs multiple servers then can also use haproxy. It is defualt behaviour of mongodb to run query on primary

Comment: we did, which you are suggesting readPref, but my concern is about high no of connections. Why it's increasing and it becomes almost same as of no of connection at Secondary.

Comment: @MukeshKumar `db.getMongo().setReadPref('secondary')` for all read goes to secondary nodes and see again if read goes to `primary` or not.  To debug   run  `sudo lsof | grep mongod | grep TCP` to primary and see which connections are opened